# semi-dynamic allocation code work in c++, but not in c, why?

Tags: c

below two codes works fine in c++ file, but compile error in c, why?
it seems to use const variable causing some problem in c,
i use dev c++ 5.11

> 19 3   C:\Users\tjc\Desktop\c練習\Untitled4.c    [Error] variable-sized object may not be initialized
>
> 19 3   C:\Users\tjc\Desktop\c練習\Untitled4.c    [Warning] excess elements in array initializer
>
> 19 3   C:\Users\tjc\Desktop\c練習\Untitled4.c    [Warning] (near initialization for 'A')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
int cmpW( const void* p1, const void*p2){
     float *pf1 = (float*)p1;
     float *pf2 = (float*)p2;
     return pf1[0] - pf2[0];
}
int cmpH( const void* p1, const void*p2){
     float *pf1 = (float*)p1;
     float *pf2 = (float*)p2;
     return pf2[1] - pf1[1];
}

int main(void)
{
     const size_t n = 5;
     float A[n][2] = {0}; //line 19
     int i=0;
     for(i=0; i<n; ++i){ // Data input.
     printf("W H: ");
     scanf("%f %f", &A[i][0], &A[i][1]);
     }
     qsort(A, n, sizeof(float) * 2, cmpW ); // By weight
     for(i=0; i<n; ++i) // Data input.
     printf("(%f, %f) ", A[i][0], A[i][1]);
     printf("\n");
     qsort(A, n, sizeof(float) * 2, cmpH ); // By height
     for(i=0; i<n; ++i) // Data input.
     printf("(%f, %f) ", A[i][0], A[i][1]);
     printf("\n");
     
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question

Comment: thanks for the reminder, already updated, please have a look!

Comment: @LingLingLing-- No. You can declare variable length arrays, but you can't _initialize_ them. Here the term **initialize** means something specific in C. You can initialize a fixed size array with, e.g., `int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };`. But you can't do this with VLAs; instead you must assign values another way. For example, by looping: `size_t sz = 5; int arr[sz]; for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) { arr[i] = i; }`. Sometimes we sloppily call this initialization, but in C this is not technically initialization, just assignment.

Comment: You should find a good C book to read about such things. C is a dangerous language to code in by guesswork.

Comment: Thanks David, you are right about VLA as i read it in C prime plus~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a difference in how C and C++ treat variables qualified as `const`.  In C, a `const` variable is not considered to be a true constant, so the declaration `float A[n][2]` is considered a variable length array, even though `n` is declared as a `const int`.

From section 6.6 (Constant expressions) of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *8* An *arithmetic  constant  expression* shall  have  arithmetic  type  and  shall  only  have operands  that  are  integer  constants, 
>   floating  constants,  enumeration  constants,  character constants,
>   `sizeof` expressions  whose  results  are  integer  constants,  and
>   `_Alignof` expressions.   Cast  operators  in  an  arithmetic  constant  expression  shall  only  convert arithmetic  types  to  arithmetic 
>   types,  except  as  part  of  an  operand  to  a `sizeof` or
>   `_Alignof` operator.

Because `A` is considered a variable length array, it may not be initialized.

From section 6.7.9 (Initialization):

> *3* The  type  of  the  entity  to  be  initialized  shall  be  an  array  of  unknown  size  or  a  complete object type **that is not a
>   variable length array type.**

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is compiler spesific error, not const variable error. If you change the code as this, the same error still exists.

```
size_t n = 5;
float A[n][2] = {0};
```

or

```
int n = 5;
float A[n][2] = {0};
```

If you set g++.exe compiler for C from Tools->Compiler Options->Program in DevC++, the problem will solve. However, this is not safe. I want to explain the cause of the problem.

Comment: i went to step as you mention from above, it has gcc.exe, g++.exe, mingw32-make.exe, gdb.exe, and gprof.exe, and it looks i dont need to change anything~ so what can i do now?

Comment: This is wrong; the error is not compiler specific, it is language specific. The error is because variable length arrays can't be initialized in C.

Comment: could you please be more detail for language specific, David?

Comment: @LingLingLing-- By language specific I mean that this is a feature of the C language, and any conforming C compiler will generate this error. C++ is a different language, and g++ is a C++ compiler. So it is the language, not the compiler.

Comment: meaning array must be declare in c, ex A[3][2]? 
in all cases?
does this also apply to all cases?

Comment: @LingLingLing: You can either write `int A[5][2] = {0};` *or* you can write `int A[n][2];`, but you *cannot* write `int A[n][2] = {0};`.  A variable-length array cannot be initialized in its declaration.

Comment: thanks John~ VLA can not be initialized in its declaration in C